# RichTextBox CaretPosition physical location

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I'm using a RichTextBox class to make some automatic text formatting. And mz question is, how do I get the RichTextBox to put some string immediately after the caret.
When I use RichTextBox.CaretPosition.InsertTextInRun("some string") the text is inserted after the current logical block, but I need to be insterted immediately after the caret, in the middle of a Run block. I hope it's clear, thx very much.

Comment: Can you explain by what you mean by 'Run Block'?

Comment: Sure, the content in the Richtextbox is stored in a Run class instance (which is a children of FlowDocument, that is used by RichTextBox to store content)

Comment: Can you put in the code for the Run class?

Comment: see some suggestions at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224243/richtextbox-and-inserting-at-caret-positions

Answer (score 0):

Well, to insert text after the caret i would do this:

```
        richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.SelectionStart, 0);
        richTextBox1.SelectedText = "textToInsert";
```

If you provide additional information in your question i will attempt to fit my answer better.

Comment: The thing is, that I'm using the WPF RichTextBox (in System.Windows namespace), that doesn't have Select method. But the solition you suggest fits my problem, I just need it for the WPF RichTextBox. Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have solved this issue by now, but I'll answer anyway.

This is what I used for a similar problem:

```
public string SelectionText
{
    get { return this.Selection.Text; }
    set { this.Selection.Text = value; }
}
```