# How do I move the caret a certain number of positions in a WPF RichTextBox?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I want to move the caret 4 positions to the right of where my caret currently is. I'm registered for `PreviewKeyDown`, and calling `InsertTextInRun()` when the tab key is captured, like so:

```
private void rtb_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
    {
        rtb.CaretPosition.InsertTextInRun("    ");
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the caret stays in place after the call to `InsertTextInRun()`. It does **not** move to the end of the new text, which is the behavior I want. How would I do this?

---

As an aside - yes, I know about the `AcceptsTab` property on `RichTextBox`. I'm choosing to ignore is and roll my own tab functionality because tabbing with `AcceptsTab` has a nasty side effect of indenting text on subsequent lines, which is **not** what I want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've just bumped into the same problem. It seems final caret position depends on which way it was moving right before the insert.

Following code makes sure (3.5sp1) that after insert, the cursor will be to the right of the inserted text:

```
 rtb.CaretPosition = rtb.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(0, LogicalDirection.Forward);
rtb.CaretPosition.InsertTextInRun(text);
```

Note that caret's LogicalDirection property may (and has to) be changed by this; it is not enough to simply create correct TextPointer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [GetInsertionPosition()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textpointer.getinsertionposition.aspx) method on the CaretPosition TextPointer. This will allow you to insert the text before the caret.

```
private void rtb_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
    {
        rtb.CaretPosition.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward).InsertTextInRun("    ");
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I must have missed that! I'll give that a try shortly, thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry, no dice. The caret did not move to the end of the inserted text.

Comment: Didn't work for me either, only solution that works is the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1):

To test, you could try forcing the movement yourself:

```
rtb.CaretPosition = rtb.Document.ContentEnd;
```

If that works, you'll probably have to implement additional logic for situations where the tab is not at the end of the content.